# SQL Server Count instances of most frequent data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do not believe what I need to do is too complicated,
but hey it's Monday morning and I could use a bit of advice.
Basically I am doing an aggregate query in SQL Server in the following format:

```
SELECT [Data1], COUNT(*), MAX([Data2])
FROM [Source]
GROUP BY [Data1]
```

However I need a 4th field as well.
A field that counts the number of times the value `MAX([Data2])` occurs.

I will make a quick example here:

```
|Data 1|Data 2|
|1     |x     |
|3     |p     |
|1     |z     |
|3     |f     |
|1     |x     |
|1     |b     |
|2     |h     |
|1     |o     |
|2     |h     |
|1     |x     |
|3     |f     |
|2     |h     |
|1     |z     |
```

Needs to produce the output:

```
|Data1|Count|Max|Occurances|
|1    |7    |x  |3         |
|2    |3    |h  |3         |
|3    |3    |f  |2         |
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for has a name in statistics.  You want the mode and the frequency of the mode.

I would approach this using two level of aggregation:

```
select data1, sum(cnt) as cnt,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then data2 end) as mode,
       max(cnt) as mode_cnt
from (select data1, data2, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by data1 order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by data1, data2
     ) t
group by data1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help -

```
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT [Data1], COUNT(*) AS Data_Count, MAX([Data2]) AS Data_Max
FROM [Source]
GROUP BY [Data1])
SELECT [Data1],Data_Count,Data_Max,COUNT(Data_Max) AS Occurances
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY [Data1],Data_Count,Data_Max
```

**Note:** I would avoid using `SQL Keywords` as column names/aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use *window function* with `cte`to make it.

use `CTE` get `COUNT` `Occurances`  by `[Data 1]` and `[Data 2]` column. then use another `CTE2` make row number order by `Occurances` desc, which mean the max amount.

```
;with cte as (
SELECT [Data 1],
       [Data 2],
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Data 1] ORDER BY [Data 1]) [count],
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Data 2],[Data 1] ORDER BY [Data 2]) Occurances
FROM T
),cte2 as (
    SELECT  
        [Data 1], 
        [Data 2],
        [count],
        Occurances,row_number() over(partition by [Data 1] order by Occurances desc) rn
    FROM cte
)

select  [Data 1], 
        [Data 2],
        [count], 
        Occurances
from cte2
where rn = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da3b98b2883f93e4b131cdc2202de6b9)

**Result**

```
Data 1  Data 2  count   Occurances
1       x         7     3
2       h         3     3
3       f         3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
DECLARE @Source AS TABLE([Data1] INT,[Data2] VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @Source VALUES
(1, 'x'), 
(3, 'p'),
(1, 'z'),
(3, 'f'),
(1, 'x'),
(1, 'b'),
(2, 'h'),
(1, 'o'),
(2, 'h'),
(1, 'x'),
(3, 'f'),
(2, 'h'),
(1, 'z')

;WITH T AS (
SELECT [Data1] , 
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [Data1]) [Count], 
    [Data2],    
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [Data2]) Occurances
FROM @Source
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES [Data1], [Count], [Data2] [Max], Occurances
FROM T 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Data1] ORDER BY Occurances DESC)
```

Result:

```
Data1       Count       Max   Occurances
----------- ----------- ----- -----------
1           7           x     3
2           3           h     3
3           3           f     2
```